# Turning off data caching asp.net

Tags: asp.net, caching

I make generous use of data caching in my asp.net application. However, my pathetic little laptop does not have the RAM to handle this making development testing hard...

Does any one know how I can temporarily turn off data caching without going through my code and adding conditionals?

Thanks!

P.S. I just want to clarify that I am **not** talking about client side caching or output caching.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable asp.net cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843343/disable-asp-net-cache)

Comment: What objects are you using for caching?

Comment: Yep this is a duplicate of that Davide and I have my answer thanks! :)

However I think my title is more descriptive

Answer (score 0):

I would abstract the caching to an interface which you can implement in 2 different ways using dependency injection or using a factory approach. This way you can work with a generic cache and leave your code as is (not worrying about whether or not caching should be used).

Comment: It would work perfectly; however, that would require me to change my code

Comment: Well, assuming you want this to work I see no problem in making the changes :)